# Jquery won't catch ajax errors with youtube api

Tags: ajax, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to get some video data and search result data from the youtube api using jquery. For some reason the code I have doesn't catch any errors. 
Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bTKU/5/) with the video id malformed. This returns an error when I test it in the console, but for some reason my code just isn't working.
I initially tried using getJson and the error handling methods there but that didn't work.

I am new to jquery and ajax especially so all the help I can get will be appreciated!

Here is my code (it is the same in the jsFiddle).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=dogs&orderby=published&alt=json&callback=?&max-results=5',
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var title = item['title']['$t'];
            var video = item['id']['$t'];
            var video = video.replace('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
            var videoID = video.replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + videoID + 'MALFORMEDID?v=2&alt=json&callback=?',
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(videoData) {
                    alert(title);
                },
                ajaxError: function(e) {
                    alert("could not find youtube vid");
                }
            });
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("oh no!");
    }
});​
```

Comment: try `dataType : jsonp` instead `json`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
error: function(e) {
```

instead of

```
ajaxError: function(e) {
```

**EDIT:**

It seems error callback won't be called when you are doing jsonp. see the manual.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

you may want to use getJSON instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: sorry that was left over from me trying out different stuff. It still doesnt work with that. But it is meant to say that.

Comment: really. I tried with your jsFiddle and it worked. what browser are you in?

Comment: seems only IE fires errors. but I found why. see my updated question

Comment: Ah thank you! With a quick read of the docs I found this: 
"JSONP
If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details."
So all I had to do was remove the "callback=?" parameters from the api urls. 
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can remove the callback parameter because you are calling URL on external domain(gdata.youtube.com). If you want to do ajax over different domains, you must use jsonp which requires callback=?